# node no file found ENOENT error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, fs

I've tried the following code to copy file from server to local file
i've created the local file (with the same name) on my root project
and use the following

```
var conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function () {
conn.sftp(function (err, sftp) {
if (err) throw err;

            var moveFrom = "/home/app/html";
            var moveTo = "/Users/i034665/WebstormProjects/apptest/index.html";

            sftp.fastGet(moveFrom, moveTo, {}, function (downloadError) {
                if (downloadError) throw downloadError;

                console.log("Succesfully uploaded");
            });
        });
    }).connect({
```

The error is:

```
    if (downloadError) throw downloadError;
    2017-08-24T23:18:56.85+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/i034665/WebstormProjects/apptest/index.html'
```

But I've created the file in the path that I've provided , Do you have an idea what the problem could be ?

I try to `chmod` the file but it doesn't help...

Comment: what platform are you using?

Comment: @JackDelson - Mac is my local machine and the file that I want to read is from linux machine

Comment: you can't copy folders like that, you need to specify files.

Comment: @dandavis but it can't find the file at all..

Comment: you never specified a source file, just a source folder and a destination file.

Comment: @dandavis - Can you please give example as answer ?

Comment: I have made some research on google, it looks like it's happened to the most people, and it looks like they could *not* find a solution,

Comment: on your mac, try `sudo chown user:staff /Users/i034665/WebstormProjects/apptest/index.html` out the user of the Mac OS to the *user* then run again

Comment: let me know what it returnsafter you've changed it to `/index.html` only ofc @JennyHilton

Comment: @JackDelson - when I try the sudo command like `Password:
chown: user: illegal user name, I put it exactly as you comment should I use `user:staff` or what ?

Comment: what is the name of the user that you are currently on? does it have access to `index.html`? @JennyHilton

Comment: @JackDelson - the user is i034665 (my user) and sure i've created this empty file(index.html) and I want to copy the content from the server to it...

Comment: `sudo chown i034665:staff /Users/i034665/WebstormProjects/apptest/index.html` try this, let me know what it returns --- *brain fried*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152799/discussion-between-jenny-hilton-and-jack-delson).

Answer (score 1):

The `.` means current directory. So it is trying to move to the path you provided but starting at the path that the program is running.

Comment: Thanks but where do you see `.` or where should I put it ?

Comment: At the error log you provided, try using a path relative to the program location and it will probably work

Comment: Not sure how to do it... can you please update your answer how should I change the code and i'll try it asap

Comment: Just try to use a destination path relative to where you are running your program instead of `/Users/i034665/WebstormProjects/apptest/` use just `/index.html`

Comment: interesting.. let me know when you try it too @JennyHilton

Comment: I've tried it and now the error is:rror: EACCES: permission denied, open '/index.html' ...

Comment: Are you running your program as an user with write privileges on the folder is running?

Comment: looks like he has no priviliges @r1verside must be a way to do that in Mac platform

Comment: Dunno about macs, too restrictive for me. Solution: install a VM of any Linux distribution you like and try from there.